# Redirect without a label in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How I can make `redirect` in Laravel without a label: `redirecting to...`?

redirecting in route file:

```
Route::get('/projects/{id}', function($id) {
    if (...) return redirect(url(...));
});
```

Comment: return->redirect(url('your page link'));

Comment: @Ashish, and I see white page with message: "Redirecting to... {my url}"...

Comment: Which version of Laravel do you use? Actually, it's not happening by default. Would you provide the all code of your controller?

Comment: @Irandoust, Laravel 5, redirecting in route file > in my question (updated).

Comment: `redirect(..)` returns a redirect response. Usually browsers just do the redirect without saying anything, I'm curious how you actually get the `Redirecting to..` message to begin with

Comment: use  redirect()->route('route_name');

Comment: What label do you speak of? Can we have a screenshot and the context?

Comment: @cbaconnier, white page with message: "Redirecting to... {my url}"

Comment: @nup the redirect function in `laravel` uses a `symfony` component to redirect, this is normally only really visible when the browser is slow, you can see the code [here](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/RedirectResponse.php#L101).

Answer (score -1):

I think you have some white spaces or invalid hidden characters before your opening PHP tag in your controller. If you don't see any white spaces, save your file as an ANSI text file, then try removing them by opening your file with a plain text editor such as Notepad and save as PHP file again. I think this solves your issue.

Comment: No, there were no spaces. =(

Answer (score -1):

try to use middleware to redirect instead of doing this from controller.